# Call an IOUSBDeviceInterface function on an obj-c object instead of a C structure

Tags: objective-c, c, usb, iokit

Let's say I want to close an USB device. Here is a C structure representing the USB device:

```
struct __USBDevice {

uint16_t idProduct;
io_service_t usbService;
IOUSBDeviceInterface **deviceHandle;
IOUSBInterfaceInterface **interfaceHandle;
Boolean open;

};

typedef struct __USBDevice *USBDeviceRef;
```

Here is the code to close the device:

```
// device is a USBDeviceRef structure
// USBDeviceClose is a function member of IOUSBDeviceInterface C Pseudoclass

(*device->deviceHandle)->USBDeviceClose(device->deviceHandle);
```

Now imagine that the device properties are declared in an obj-c class

```
@interface Device : NSObject {

NSNumber idProduct
io_service_t usbService;
IOUSBDeviceInterface **deviceHandle;
IOUSBInterfaceInterface **interfaceHandle;
BOOL open;
}

@end
```

How would I do to call USBDeviceClose() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways.  You can either model your class similar to a struct, and add `@public` above your declarations (that way the syntax won't change) or you can add a `Close` method to your interface which will do the same logic internally (but without the need to dereference `device` of course).

Comment: Could you provide a quick code example for the first way ? Thank you.

Comment: I already did, simply add `@public` above all your iVars.  Then you can access them like this `device->idProduct` etc.

Answer (score 0):

No need to be redundant.  Ivars can be structs.

```
@interface Device : NSObject {

USBDeviceRef deviceRef;
}

@end

#implementation Device

- (void) close {
USBDeviceClose(deviceRef->deviceHandle);
}
```

Comment: Haven't you forget (*deviceRef->deviceHandle)-> just before USBDeviceClose ?